# npm run build generates more files than just bundle.js bundle.css

Tags: npm, webpack, bundle, bundler

I'm working on a SPA with Vue.js and Django.

I run `npm run build` to generate the bundle files that will be used in production. I was expecting to only generate two files: `dist/bundle.js` and `dist/bundle.css`. However, besides the aforemetnioned files, a third js file is also being generated: `dist/js/about.add8abe8.js`.

Why is this?

In my Django project, inside the frontend/src/views/ directory I have 3 Vue components: Home.vue, List.vue and About.vue.

***EDIT:***

I don't have a `webpack.config` file. But these are some other files that may be relevant:

***package.json***:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.19",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.4.2-beta"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

***vue.config***:

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

module.exports = {
  // on Windows you might want to set publicPath: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
  publicPath: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
  outputDir: "./dist/",

  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin("BundleTracker")
      .use(BundleTracker, [{ filename: "./webpack-stats.json" }]);

    config.output.filename("bundle.js");

    config.optimization.splitChunks(false);

    config.resolve.alias.set("__STATIC__", "static");

    config.devServer
      .hotOnly(true)
      .watchOptions({ poll: 1000 })
      .https(false)
      .disableHostCheck(true)
      .headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["*"] });
  },

  // uncomment before executing 'npm run build'
  css: {
    extract: {
      filename: "bundle.css",
      chunkFilename: "bundle.css"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Show your package.json `scripts.build` command and webpack config if there is one. It could be because your app is using lazy loading js method.

Comment: show all the project if you can.. it is proably what @pako said.

Comment: @pako thanks. I just added my package.json and vue.config files. I don't have a webpack.config file however.

Comment: @Xar: try to do steps from this article https://itnext.io/vuidget-how-to-create-an-embeddable-vue-js-widget-with-vue-custom-element-674bdcb96b97 `"4. Disable chunks" `

Comment: @Pako. That worked. Thank you! You can write the complete answer if you want and I'll mark it as the acceped answer.